# How can I send a data from collectionView to another view (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _categoryModel = [[CategoryModel alloc] initWithCategoryName:self.titleee[indexPath.row]];
    _dataIndex = indexPath.row;
    self.data = self.titleee[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@",self.data); 
    [self passDataDorward];
}

-(void)passDataDorward{
    CategoryItemViewController *categoryVC = [[CategoryItemViewController alloc] init];
    categoryVC.dataText = self.titleee[_dataIndex];
}
```

I got true data on NSLog  but I could not send data to CategoryItemViewController. dataText variable always null. Why ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    _categoryModel = [[CategoryModel alloc] initWithCategoryName:self.titleee[indexPath.row]];
    _dataIndex = indexPath.row;
    self.data = self.titleee[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@",self.data);
    [self passDataForward:indexPath.row];
}

-(void)passDataForward:(NSInteger)dataIndex {
    CategoryItemViewController *categoryVC = [[CategoryItemViewController alloc] init];
    categoryVC.dataText = self.titleee[dataIndex];
}
```

Please try this.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you have created a property in *CategoryItemViewController.h* file like

```
@property NSString *dataText;
```

Now, instead of taking global reference to the selected index you can pass the data to the method as Arguments like below,

```
[self passDataDorward:self.titleee[indexPath.row]];
```

Now change the method as below

`-(void)passDataDorward:(NSString* )dataText{
    CategoryItemViewController *categoryVC = [[CategoryItemViewController alloc] init];
    categoryVC.dataText = dataText;
}`

Hope this will resolve your issue.